# Pagination with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape using selenium and python, the web page have a paginator in javascript, when I click in the button, I can see that the content reload but when I try to get the new table information it's the same old table info, selenium doesn't noticed that de DOM info has changed, I'm aware about the stale DOM, I'm just looking for the best path to solve this problem

````
for link in source.find_all('div', {'class': 'company-row d-flex'}):
    print(link.a.text, link.small.text, link.find('div', {'class': 'col-2'}).text)

# Next button (I´ll make an iterator)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="hrefcurrentpage=2"]').click()

# Tried this and doesn't work
# time.sleep(5)

# Here the table change but get the same old info 
for link in source.find_all('div', {'class': 'company-row d-flex'}):
    print(link.a.text, link.small.text, link.find('div', {'class': 'col-2'}).text)  ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting the same data after opening the next page even after delay since you are getting your data from the existing `source`.
So, you should re-read, reload the `source` after clicking the pagination, possibly with some delay.

Comment: You are always clicking the same button. `//a[@href="hrefcurrentpage=2"]` you have to increase the page number to 3, 4 etc here

Comment: No I don't, the first and the second print are giving me the same info and I'm clicking on the button, must be different, I'm seeing how it changes in the browser

Comment: Seems you have to reload the `source`. See my updated answer.